# Datatable duplicando elementos

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-datatables, datatable

Eu tenho um pesquisa feita com Ajax via JQuery que retorna uma tableta com DataTable. Porém os elementos do DataTable estão duplicando conforme eu mando pesquisar (vide print).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei utilizar o destroy, mas aí ela deixa de criar a tabela. Meu código está assim no momento.
JavaScript:

```
$(".pesquisar").on("click", function () {

    $("#pesquisar").submit(function (event) {

        // Stop form from submitting normally
        event.preventDefault();
        // Get some values from elements on the page:
        var $form = $(this);
        var inputs = $('#pesquisar').serialize();
        var url = $form.attr("action");
        // Send the data using post
        var posting = $.post(url, inputs);
        // Put the results in a div
        posting.done(function (data) {
            destroiDataTable();
            $("#resultado").append(data);
        });
    });
});

function destroiDataTable() {
    $("#resultado").html("");
    $(".datatable").destroy();
}

$('.datatable').DataTable({
    destroy: true,
    retrieve: true,
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
    ],
    "oLanguage": {
        buttons: {
            "copy": "Copiar",
            "print": "Imprimir"
        },
        "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros por página",
        "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
        "sInfo": "Mostrando de _START_ a _END_ no total de _TOTAL_ registro(s)",
        "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 de 0 registros",
        "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de _MAX_ registros)",
        "sSearch": "Pesquisar: ",
        "oPaginate": {
            "sFirst": "Início",
            "sPrevious": "Anterior",
            "sNext": "Próximo",
            "sLast": "Último"
        }
    }
});
```

Minha tabela que vem no retorno PHP está assim:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered datatable" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nº Chamado</th>
                <th>Abertura</th>
                <th>Usuário</th>
                <th>Descrição</th>
                <th>Assunto</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Opções</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <?php
            echo
            "<tr>
                <td>{$chamados->cha_codigo[$i]}</td>
                <td>{$chamados->cha_data_hora_abertura[$i]}</td>
                <td>{$chamados->usu_nome[$i]}</td>
                <td>{$chamados->cha_descricao[$i]}</td>
                <td>{$chamados->cha_assunto[$i]}</td>
                <td>{$chamados->cha_status[$i]}</td>
                <td> - </td>
            </tr>";
            ?>
        </tbody>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Nº Chamado</th>
                <th>Abertura</th>
                <th>Usuário</th>
                <th>Descrição</th>
                <th>Assunto</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Opções</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Alguém sabe me deixar o que está acontecendo e como eu posso resolver isso?

Comment: Substitua `$("#resultado").append(data);` por `$("#resultado").html(data);`

Comment: Continua duplicando do mesmo jeito. Se eu coloco o destroy ele só não aparece nada.

Comment: será que já não esta vindo duplicado o "data" da sua consulta?

Comment: Coloca um console.log para ver se o evento de submit (ou click) não esta sendo chamado duas vezes, também pode ser algum problema com sincronia dos métodos também.

Comment: UPeralta, edita sua pergunta e coloca a solução como resposta, assim mais pessoas poderão aproveitar essa solução

Comment: Soluções devem estar na área de respostas, não como edição da pergunta.

Comment: Desculpa gente, eu sou novo no Stackoverflow ainda. Vou colocar como resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver colocando uma variável para verificar se já existia uma requisição Ajax anterior e, caso tenha, abortá-la.
O código ficou assim:

```
var pending;

$(".pesquisar").on("click", function () {

    if (pending) { //there is an ajax request running
        pending.abort();
        return; //do nothing
    }

    pending = $("#pesquisar").submit(function (event) {
        // Stop form from submitting normally
        event.preventDefault();
        // Get some values from elements on the page:
        var $form = $(this);
        var inputs = $('#pesquisar').serialize();
        var url = $form.attr("action");
        // Send the data using post
        var posting = $.post(url, inputs);
        // Put the results in a div
        posting.done(function (data) {
            $("#resultado").html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

O que está na pergunta mas não está na resposta é porquê não foi alterado.
Agradeço a todos pela ajuda.